# Why retrofit fetches data from asp web service too slow

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, mvp, android-mvp

I have written an android app but it fetches data from server too slow
I used rxjava and retrofit for fetching data and web services have been written by asp.net
please tell me what should I do
I have checked web services with postman and they are fine and fast
please review my codes and tell me what's wrong with them
these are my codes:
Fragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends BaseFragment implements HomeContract.View {

    private HomeContract.Presenter presenter;
    private SliderView slider;
    private TextView txt_homeFragment_showAllNew,
            txt_homeFragment_showAllTopSelling,
            txt_homeFragment_showAllHits;
    private RecyclerView rv_homeFragment_newProduct,
            rv_homeFragment_topSelling,
            rv_homeFragment_hits,
            rv_homeFragment_specialOffer;
    private Button btn_homeFragment_showAllSpecial;
    private HomeRecyclerAdapter adapter;
    private Fragment fragment;
    private FragmentTransaction transaction;
    private Bundle bundle;
    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private Dialog myDialog;

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        String pls = getResources().getString(R.string.please_wait);
        String loading = getResources().getString(R.string.loading);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        presenter = new HomePresenter(new TCommerceRepository(),getViewContext());
        if(MainFragment.checkInternet) {
            presenter.getNewProduct();
            presenter.getHitsProduct();
            presenter.getSlider();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getLayout() {
        return R.layout.fragment_home;
    }

    @Override
    public void setupViews() {
        myDialog = new Dialog(getContext());
        myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_alert);
        TextView txtTitle = myDialog.findViewById(R.id.txt_alertDialog_title);
        TextView txtMessage = myDialog.findViewById(R.id.txt_alertDialog_message);

        String pls = getResources().getString(R.string.please_wait);
        String loading = getResources().getString(R.string.loading);
        txtTitle.setText(loading);
        txtMessage.setText(pls);
        myDialog.getWindow().setLayout(1000,500);


        slider = rootView.findViewById(R.id.slider_homeFragment_slideShow);
        txt_homeFragment_showAllNew = rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_homeFragment_showAllNew);
        txt_homeFragment_showAllTopSelling = rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_homeFragment_showAllTopSelling);
        txt_homeFragment_showAllHits = rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_homeFragment_showAllHits);
        rv_homeFragment_newProduct = rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_homeFragment_newProduct);
        rv_homeFragment_topSelling = rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_homeFragment_topSelling);
        rv_homeFragment_hits = rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_homeFragment_hits);
        rv_homeFragment_specialOffer = rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_homeFragment_specialOffer);
        btn_homeFragment_showAllSpecial = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_homeFragment_showAllSpecial);




        txt_homeFragment_showAllNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                bundle  = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("flag",1);
                fragment = new StockListFragment();
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                transaction = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.frm_mainFragment_mainLayout, fragment);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });

        txt_homeFragment_showAllTopSelling.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("flag",2);
                fragment = new StockListFragment();
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                transaction = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.frm_mainFragment_mainLayout, fragment);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });

        txt_homeFragment_showAllHits.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("flag",3);
                fragment = new StockListFragment();
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                transaction = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.frm_mainFragment_mainLayout, fragment);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public Context getViewContext() {
        return getContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void showMessage(String msg) {
        Log.i("LOG::::" , msg);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        presenter.attachView(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        presenter.detachView();
    }

    @Override
    public void showNewProduct(StockListModel list) {


        adapter = new HomeRecyclerAdapter(getViewContext() , list);
        rv_homeFragment_newProduct.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getViewContext() , RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL , false));
        rv_homeFragment_newProduct.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void showTopSellProduct(StockListModel list) {
        adapter = new HomeRecyclerAdapter(getViewContext() , list);
        rv_homeFragment_topSelling.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getViewContext() , RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL , false));
        rv_homeFragment_topSelling.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void showHitsProduct(StockListModel list) {

        adapter = new HomeRecyclerAdapter(getViewContext() , list);
        rv_homeFragment_hits.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getViewContext() , RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL , false));
        rv_homeFragment_hits.setAdapter(adapter);
        if (myDialog.isShowing()){
            myDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void showSlider(ItemImageSlider itemImageSlider) {

        if ((myDialog.isShowing())){
            myDialog.dismiss();
        } else {
            myDialog.show();
        }

        TimerTask task = slider.getTimerTask();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(task,5000,2000);

        ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < itemImageSlider.getItems().size(); i++) {
            urls.add(itemImageSlider.getItems().get(i).getIcon());
        }
        slider.setUrls(urls);



    }
}
```

Presenter:

```
public class HomePresenter implements HomeContract.Presenter {

    private HomeContract.View view;
    private TCommerceDataSource tCommerceDataSource;
    private CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();

    private Context context;

    HomePresenter (TCommerceDataSource tCommerceDataSource,Context context){

            this.tCommerceDataSource = tCommerceDataSource;
            this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    public void attachView(HomeContract.View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    public void detachView() {
        this.view = null;
        if (compositeDisposable != null){
            compositeDisposable.clear();
            
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void getNewProduct() {


            tCommerceDataSource.getListStockNew().subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new SingleObserver<StockListModel>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                            compositeDisposable.add(d);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(StockListModel productList) {
                            view.showNewProduct(productList);
                            view.showTopSellProduct(productList);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
                            view.showMessage(e.toString());

                        }
                    });



    }
    @Override
    public void getHitsProduct() {

            tCommerceDataSource.getListStockBestView().subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new SingleObserver<StockListModel>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                            compositeDisposable.add(d);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(StockListModel stockListModel) {
                            view.showHitsProduct(stockListModel);


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
                            view.showMessage(e.toString());

                        }
                    });


    }

    @Override
    public void getSlider() {

            tCommerceDataSource.getSlideImage().subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new SingleObserver<ItemImageSlider>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                            compositeDisposable.add(d);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(ItemImageSlider itemImageSlider) {
                            view.showSlider(itemImageSlider);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
                            view.showMessage(e.toString());

                        }
                    });


    }
}
```

and these are my Okhttp client and interceptor:

```
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(6 , TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .readTimeout(6 , TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                        Request request = chain.request()
                                .newBuilder()
                                .build();
                        return chain.proceed(request);
                    }
                }).build();
        
        return httpClient;
```

How Should I use Interceptor?
What should I change?

Comment: why not use an interceptor to see the response time and other info?

Comment: I have used interceptor. How should I see response time and other info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Sample how to use, (not an answer - just for debugging)

```
   public class LoginInterceptor extends Interceptor {
        private static final String TAG = LoginInterceptor.class.getSimpleName() + " : ";
    
    
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();
    
            long t1 = System.nanoTime();
    
            Log.i(TAG, String.format("Sending request %s on %s%n%s",
                    request.url(), chain.connection(), request.headers()));
    
    
            Response response = chain.proceed(request);
    
            long t2 = System.nanoTime();
    
    
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("Received response for %s in %.1fms%n%s",
                    response.request().url(), (t2 - t1) / 1e6d, response.headers()));
    
            return response;
        }
```

and add this to client

> .addNetworkInterceptor(new LoginInterceptor())

Comment: has app problem or server?: 2020-08-16 17:24:48.153 15571-15654/com.intechdev.tcommerce D/Inter: Received response for http://tc.intechserver.ir/wservice/default.aspx?Action=Items&module=Prod&type=Products&sort=2&native=1&showimage=2 in 24216.3ms
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Pragma: no-cache,no-cache
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    Content-Encoding: gzip
    Expires: -1
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
    X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
    Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=yy2xlvydmh4dyramwv1z053f; path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Comment: kindly remove the api in the above comment if it is important, Now as to query, the response output is very big json,  but it should not take 24216.3ms as you mentioned above. Test the api in Postman client app in Windows.

Comment: I have tested that in post man. but the response is so fast

Comment: Have you got same result when tested with different devices or emulator

Comment: Yes, it's same with different devices